# How to create Horizontal scrolling Buttons/TextViews which gets highlighted with an elliptical shape in the background on click

Tags: android, css, xml

I am creating an android application where I need to insert a horizontal scrolling text Views which gets highlighted onClick with elliptical colored shape in the background. Also, the background shape should be removed if another Text View is selected and the new selected text View gets highlighted. I think its like Radio Buttons but with different style.

Please refer the image below :-

[click here for the image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKxzp.png)

I have no idea if these are scrolling TextViews or Buttons.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you provide the link or attach an image for your requested control ?

Comment: @Saurabh7474  You can click the link.

Comment: Use a RecyclerView with Horizontal orientation to display the list. Each item will be a TextView on an Imageview with elliptical background where all ImageViews are hidden initially. Inside the RecyclerView Adapter, add a boolean variable named isClicked to the ViewHolder and change it to true on click of this item and change all others to false at the same time. Next, you call notifyDataSetChanged() which will call onBindViewHolder(...){}, where you may show/ hide the background as per the value of isClicked for each item.

Answer (score 0):

```
public final class SelectionRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SelectionRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {


private int mSelectedPosition = -1;
private ArrayList<String> mList;
private OnSelectionListener mListener;

public FilterRecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<String> list, OnFilterClickListener callback) {
    mList = list;
    mListener = callback;
}

@Override
public FilterRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_textview, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mTextView.setText(mList.get(position))

    if(position == mSelectedPosition){
      holder.mTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }else{
      holder.mTextview.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }

    // You can use selector drawable resource and call holder.mTextView.setSelected(true or false);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mList.size();
}


class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {


    private TextView mTextView;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mTextView = (TextView) itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (mListener == null) {
            return;
        }

        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        if (mSelectedPosition == position) {
            return;
        }

        mSelectedPosition = position;

        YourModel item = mList.get(position);
        mListener.onSelect(getAdapterPosition(), item);

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

public void getSelecetedPosition(){
  return mSelected;
}

public boolean hasSelection(){
   return mSelectedPosition != -1;
}

public interface OnSelectionListener {
    void onSelect(int position, YourModel model);
}
}
```

This is how your adapter looks like.

You can find examples from web about horizantal recyclerview scrolling. You can attach LinearSnapHelper to recyclerview for better user experince.

Inflated layout :

```
<TextView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:gravity="center"/>
```

You need to create your own selector drawable which has selectedState=true and no state defined items inside it if you want to use View.setSelected(value). Otherwise you can just basicly set your shape to background instead Color.RED;

Good luck there.

Emre